# how do i use tor proxy with my client/server chat app cpp

Tags: c++, proxy, chat, tor

I have a client/server app, and I want my client to use tor proxy which I've downloaded from the tor website, and connect over that proxy with my server that has an onion address.

I have the code that uses the proxy but the problem is that the server is designed to send an authentication string that needs to be changed in a certain way so that only my clients can be accepted to connect to the server.

but when the proxy checks, if the server is up. my server sends the authentication string to the proxy.

**The question is how do I know that is the proxy is checking the server instead of the client from the server's end?**

at the server's end, I do nothing but listen and accept the client as if you would do using sockets without a proxy.